# jQuery extract url and place into .load()

Tags: jquery, tabs, load, this, dynamic-url

I'm trying to load external php into a div on click, works fine like this:

```
$('.tab1').click(function(){
    $('#place').hide(500, function(){
        $('#place').load('example1.inc', function(){
        $('#place').show(500);
        });
    });
});
$('.tab2').click(function(){
    $('#place').hide(500, function(){
        $('#place').load('example2.inc', function(){
        $('#place').show(500);
        });
    });
});
```

the problem is obvious, so I've been trying to narrow it down with no success.  I figured to place links in the tabs (no longer using unique ids for the tabs), and extract the link to place into .load() -

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    var location = $('a', this).attr('href');
    $('#place').hide(500, function() {
        $('#place').load(location, function() {
        $('#place').show(500);
        });
    });
});
```

this is way way off - and load only takes a url as first argument so...

My question is how can I place the appropriately clicked tab's URL into the load method?

btw I'm pretty new at this - is the first way I have it THAT bad?  I mean when I have something like 5 tabs its pretty cleat that I'm doing it wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any issue with your second example, what's the problem with it?

Comment: in first you are using class not id's and your second one seem to be right ?

Comment: Sounds like @Arun is right - you said you were "no longer using unique ids". If you are using the period selector, you weren't using IDs in the first place. In jQuery, selectors can be `$(".class")` and `$("#id")`

Comment: hmmm... second one is simply loading the link as a page, not into the #place div.  the first is just bad re-writting example, but it worked. perhaps i should place the .tab into the 'a', as opposed to a into the tab.

Comment: sorry  can't understand your requirement...is really something not working ??

Comment: not working in the slightest.  just acting as any old link.  perhaps I need to do something to the html <a> part so it isn't an active link?  <span class="tab"><a href="ext1.inc">blah</a></span> ?

Comment: Yeah thanks Blade0rz & Arun - that was a mistake in the phrasing of the question.  I meant classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the second one is simply loading the link as a page, not into the #place div

This is because you did not prevent the click event on the `a` by using `preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
$('.tab a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).attr('href'), $place = $('#place');

    $place.hide(500, function() {
        $place.load(location, function() {
            $place.show(500);
        });
    });
});
```